# No radio group buttons shown in toolbar

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have this Coffee code for ExtJS v3.4. This to add two radio buttons in a toolbar. Somehow these do not get rendered at all. The toolbar is still empty. What am I missing here?

```
@tbar = new Ext.Toolbar(
  items: [
    new Ext.form.RadioGroup(
      columns: 2
      xtype: 'radiogroup'
      name: radioGroupName
      layout: 'column'
      fieldLabel: 'A group'
      items: [
        new Ext.form.Radio(
          boxLabel: 'One'
          name:     radioGroupName
          checked:  true
          inputValue: '1'
        )
        new Ext.form.Radio(
          boxLabel: 'Two'
          name:     radioGroupName
          inputValue: '2'
        )
      ]
    )
  ]
)
```

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: Just to eliminate any possible Coffee impact, did you try JavaScript code directly?

Comment: Of course. No change. Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here?

You are expecting too much from ExtJS 3.4 :)

Either specify `layout: 'form'` on the toolbar, or `width` on the radiogroup. In the latter case, `fieldLabel` won't work as it requires `form` layout in ExtJS 3.4.

Also note that there is no `layout` option on [`radiogroup` in ExtJS 3.4](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup).